# Anyway to allow base64 encoded images in mediawiki?

Tags: image, base64, mediawiki

I'm using mediawiki 1.17 so I tried both:

```
$wgAllowImageTag = true;
$wgRawHtml = true; #I know it's insecure just wanted to see if it'd work
```

My img tags of the form:

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhDwAPAKECAAAAzMzM/////
wAAACwAAAAADwAPAAACIISPeQHsrZ5ModrLlN48CXF8m2iQ3YmmKqVlRtW4ML
wWACH+H09wdGltaXplZCBieSBVbGVhZCBTbWFydFNhdmVyIQAAOw=="
alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```

Are getting rendered as:

```
<img alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150" />
```

If i edit the page, the img tag still has all the data.

### Background

I'm exporting kb articles from my CRM system (sugarcrm).  Sugar encodes the images linked to each KB article in base64.  This makes it pretty convenient for syncing those images to the mediawiki site without having to export / relink images.  So, would be great if I could get mediawiki to allow the base64 encoded images.  In my case our mediawiki site is not edited by the general public, just members of our company.

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on [$wgAllowExternalImages = true;](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgAllowExternalImages)

I know technically it isn't an external image, but maybe mediawiki is treating it as such. You could also try [whitelisting it](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgEnableImageWhitelist).

Comment: Just gave it a try.  No dice.  I didn't try whitelisting b/c not sure what'd i'd whitelist... "data:image/gif"  Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's unlikely that you still need this, it may help others: I just created some patch instructions to make MediaWiki (and the CKeditor-based WYSIWYG extension) support base64 images.

https://github.com/limasierra/MediaWiki-Base64-patch

hth